# Polynomial function college algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The polynomial of degree $4,$

has a root of multiplicity $2$ at $x=4$

and roots of multiplicity $1$ at $x=0$ and $x=−4$

It goes through the point $(5,13.5)$

Find a formula for $P(x)$.

Comment: Hint: The product of a polynomial with root at $x=a$ and a polynomial with root at $x=b$ is a polynomial with roots at $x=a$ and $x=b$.

Comment: Do you know that if $r$ is a root, then $x-r$ is a factor and that if $r$ is a root of multiplicity $n$ then $(x-r)^n$ is a factor? In addition you can assume that there is some number $a$ which is a constant factor. This is all you need to know to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

By the roots and multiplicities given, we know that $(x-4)^2, x, (x+4)$ are factors of $P$. Thus,

$$P(x) = Q(x)(x-4)^2(x)(x+4)$$

where $Q(x)$ is some polynomial. Notice that$ (x-4)^2(x)(x+4)$ has degree $4$ (just sum the multiplicities), and $P(x)$ has degree $4$, and thus $Q(x)$ must have degree $0$, in other words, it must be a constant which we'll just call $Q$. Thus,

$$P(x) = Q\cdot (x-4)^2(x)(x+4).$$
 Since $(5,13.5)$ is a point on $P$, then you can substitute that point in the formula above (using $x=5$, $P(x)=13.5$) and solve for $Q$.

Answer (score 0):

using what we know about the roots, $P(x)  = q\times x(x+4)(x-4)^2$ so that when $x = 4,-4,0$ you get $P(x) = 0$

we have to get $q$ now, we know $13.5 = q \times 5 \times 9 = 45q$ so $q = \dfrac{13.5}{45} = 0.3$

therefore $P(x) = 0.3x(x+4)(x-4)^2$